# by() function in R: could not find mean function

Tags: r

This is my code and output:

```
by(ncbirths$weight, ncbirths$habit, mean)
Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : could not find function "FUN"
```

If I try to pass other common functions like sd and summary to by(), I get the expected output.

Comment: This seems to work just fine: `ncbirths <- data.frame(weight=rnorm(20, 100,20), habit=rep(1:2, each=10)); by(ncbirths$weight, ncbirths$habit, mean)`. Did you redefine `mean` in your environment? See if "mean" is listed under `conflicts()`. Try `rm(mean)` to get rid of your shadowed version. And don't name variables using names of base functions in the future.

Comment: ah, thanks. Brain fart. Not sure when or how I assigned 'mean' to a value, odd. When I used mean in tapply, and when 'mean' had an assigned value, it worked. Know how to account for the difference?

Comment: Well, it looks like `tapply()` uses `match.fun` to find the function. So if you had `mean<-"mean"` it would work. But `by()` seems to call the function directly for some reason. So they no have slightly different ways in which they treat the `FUN=` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely that's you've assigned something to a variable named `mean` which is masking the `base::mean()` function. You can confirm this by looking in the list of `conflicts()`. For example

```
mean <- "doesnotexist"
ncbirths <- data.frame(weight=rnorm(20, 100,20), habit=rep(1:2, each=10))

by(ncbirths$weight, ncbirths$habit, mean)
# Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : could not find function "FUN"

tapply(ncbirths$weight, ncbirths$habit, mean)
# Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
#   object 'doesnotexist' of mode 'function' was not found
```

However, if the value you set for mean is the name of a function, `tapply()` will still work because it uses "match.fun" to resolve the `FUN=` parameter whereas `by()` does not and attempts to call the function directly

```
mean <- "mean"

by(ncbirths$weight, ncbirths$habit, mean)
# Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : could not find function "FUN"

tapply(ncbirths$weight, ncbirths$habit, mean)
#         1         2 
# 108.16228  96.78932
```

Just be sure to remove your local version of mean

```
rm(mean)
```

or call the base version explicitly

```
by(ncbirths$weight, ncbirths$habit, base::mean)
```